# Using %in% in data.table with regular expression

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I have a `data.table` and a vector containg character strings. I can manipulate the data.table, but not not vector `x` as this contains values from a file header.

```r
DT <- data.table::data.table(c("A", "B", "C"))
x <- c("A (xy)", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```

I'd like to check which strings of `DT$V1` are not contained in `x` (complete or partially specified by regex).
(Or with my use case: I'd like to check which values of `DT$V1` are not contained as columns in a file).
So in this example, all rows are matched and the output is an emtpy data.table because `A` is contained in `A (xy)` and `B`, `C` matches completely.

So, basically `DT[!V1 %in% x]` but e.g. using a regular expression for `V1` as this expression excludes `A`.

I've already tried `grepl(paste(DT$V1, collapse = '|'), x)` as suggested by answers to similar questions which works totally fine but yields the indeces of the vector, not the data.table.

Comment: I am confused. What is your expected output given your DT?

Comment: thanks for your hint, I added a sentence for the output I expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DT[sapply(V1, function(i) any(grepl(i, x)))]
```

Comment: Definitely works, thanks! Though is there any more efficient way?

Comment: @ThomasFuchs an easy speedup would be adding `fixed=TRUE` and using `vapply()`. `DT[vapply(V1, function(i) any(grepl(i, x), fixed = TRUE), logical(1L))]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to go over each element of `DT$V1` to test if `grep` finds it in `x`. As you are using also `()` it would be good to set `fixed = TRUE`. When `colSums` is larger than `0` there was a hit which can be negatiat with `!` to get *strings of `DT$V1` are not contained in `x`*.

```
DT$V1[!colSums(sapply(DT$V1, grepl, x, fixed = TRUE)) > 0]
#character(0)
```